# How to update specific single column with multiple columns in an update query using php?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement

I have one table called `Master` and it has four columns called `id`, `A`, `B` and  `C`.

When I update the table, I need to modify the specific single column that a user selected. For example, if a user selected column `A` then only `A` records will get updated in the database. If the user selects `C` then only `C` records will updated.

Below is the code I tried, but it is updating all columns. Would you help me in this?

```
$column_name=$row['column_name'];//A,B,C
if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $A=$row['A'];
        $B=$row['B'];
        $C=$row['C'];
      }}

 UPDATE Master SET $column_name='$A'+20, $column_name='$B'+30, $column_name='$C'+50 WHERE user_id='$id'";
```

Comment: Now what database system _are_ you using? `MySQL` or `MS SQL server`? You gave _both_ tags to your question which does not make sense.

Comment: I am sorry, I am using MySQL.

Comment: Why are there 3 variables if you're only updating one column?

Comment: Incidentally, this code only updates one column

Answer (score 1):

> Although your requirement is not fully clear to me so then i think it
>   will be helped you to meet your requirement. It is a dynamic solution. If it's not you can clarify your requirement i will must be try my best to resolve it. Thanks for asking.

```
* table schema is stakcoverflow
* table name is master_tbl
* fields name 
id | a | b | c


<?php 
$myHost = "localhost"; // use your real host name ex. myDomainName.com
$myUserName = "root";   // use your real login user name ex. myUserName
$myPassword = "";   // use your real login password ex. myPassword
$myDataBaseName = "stakcoverflow"; // use your real database name ex. myDataBaseName

$con = mysqli_connect( "$myHost", "$myUserName", "$myPassword", "$myDataBaseName" );

if( !$con ) // == null if creation of connection object failed
{ 
    // report the error to the user, then exit program
    die("connection object not created: ".mysqli_error($con));
}

if( mysqli_connect_errno() )  // returns false if no error occurred
{ 
    // report the error to the user, then exit program
    die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
} 

$sql="SELECT a,b,c,id FROM master_tbl ORDER BY id";
$affectedrowsno  = 0;
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    // Get field information for all fields
    while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result))
    {
        $column_name = $fieldinfo->name;
        // Get field information for all fields

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $a = $row['a'];
            $b = $row['b'];
            $c = $row['c'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            $sql = "UPDATE master_tbl SET $column_name=$a+20, $column_name=$b+50, $column_name=$c+80 WHERE id=$id";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $affectedrowsno += count(mysqli_affected_rows($con));
        }

   }
   echo "Affected rows = " . $affectedrowsno;
   // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Didar Alam, Can you explain me $affectedrowsno += count(mysqli_affected_rows($con)); and can I use the update query outside of while statement?

Comment: No. Because it is not increment then. you will always get 1 if you  put it outer side of the loop. if your update query run out side of loop then you can. As it inside of loop then each execute it does return affected rows 1. Hope you understand. And if you want to update query run outside of the loop then you have to gather all data in an array and you have to manage them for update query itself syntax and with your need.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use if statement:

```
$column_name=$row['column_name'];//A,B,C
if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $A=$row['A'];
        $B=$row['B'];
        $C=$row['C'];
      }}

    if($column_name == 'A'){
       UPDATE Master SET A='$A'+20 WHERE user_id='$id'";
    } elseif($column_name == 'B'){
       UPDATE Master SET B ='$B'+30 WHERE user_id='$id'";
    }elseif($column_name == 'C'){
       UPDATE Master SET C ='$C'+50 WHERE user_id='$id'";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Ahmad, I have one doubt Incase if we have more than 3 column then every time we have to create if statement? or any easy way?

Comment: You have a specific number to add in each case! : 20,30,50,  so you have to  check for column name. If the number that you have to add is the same for all, e.g. 20 , then there is no need for `if` statement :  `UPDATE Master SET $column_name ='$column_name'+20 WHERE user_id='$id'";`     -    You can use `CASE ... WHEN` statement in mysql, but this way only transforms if statement from php to mysql!

Comment: Thanks for replying again. I have $column_name=$A (This value i am getting from other table) + 20 (Number is different)

Comment: Well perhaps that's not such a great idea then?

Comment: @NarendraVerma you can use swith case  statement in php instead of `if` , for less code